# Implementing two consumables with MKStoreKit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

How should I implement two consumables with MKStoreKit? If I have two consumables, for example "handful of coins" (**10 coins**) and "bag with coins" (**100 coins**). I have two questions:

1. How should product IDs look like?
2. How to get overall amount of purchased coins, including ones from handful(s) and from bag(s)?

   ```
   Amount = 10*handfuls_purchased + 100*bags_purchased;
   ```

I've read tutorial on official MKStoreKit blog but I still just can't figure this out.

P.s. I'm using MKStoreKit 3.1 and can't update to more recent version because of ARC (my project doesn't support it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your plist's consumables key should look like this.

```
<key>Consumables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.yourcompany.yourapp.handfulofcoins</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Count</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>CoinsInMyApp</string>
        </dict>
<key>com.yourcompany.yourapp.bagofcoins</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Count</key>
            <integer>100</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>CoinsInMyApp</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I match the String "CoinsInMyApp" to calculate the number of purchased coins no matter which consumable they come from. In the above example if the user buys 1 bagofcoins and 2 handfulofcoins, MKStoreManager stores 120 for the key CoinsInMyApp.

methods,

```
- (BOOL) canConsumeProduct:(NSString*) productIdentifier
- (BOOL) canConsumeProduct:(NSString*) productIdentifier quantity:(int) quantity
```

will tell you if you have enough products.

When the player uses coins, you should let MKStoreKit know this by calling

```
- (BOOL) consumeProduct:(NSString*) productIdentifier quantity:(int) quantity
```

You can get the number of coins by calling

```
[[MKStoreManager numberForKey:@"CoinsInMyApp"] intValue];
```

PS: You can use MKStoreKit latest version in a non-ARC project by compiling it with the -fobjc-arc flag.

I wrote about this here http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question, if you allow: I give 3 coins to user when he or she launch game for the first time:  `if ([MKStoreManager objectForKey:GoldenCoinsID] == nil) [MKStoreManager setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:GoldenCoinsID];`

Comment: It doesn't work in the newest version, because there is no more public method [MKStoreManager objectForKey:]

Comment: I know this is an old post, but does MKStoreKit restore Consumables?